# Access to a private server through a public server

Tags: apache, private, public, bridge

I have two servers (apache http) but only one public IP address and I need to make both accesible. The two servers are in the same LAN, so you can access to one of these servers from the another.

- Server 1 (Apache P:80) <- Public IP
- Server 2 (Apache P:2300 for example) <- Private IP

Is there some way to show  the contents (a webpage) of Server 2 using Server 1 like a "bridge" (without losing the accesibility to the webpage hosted in server 1)?? Thanks a lot.

PD: I can't modify the router rules

Comment: Write some PHP to forward requests to the Private IP web server and return the content that it sends back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Apache reverse proxy: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html